# Verifying hiera lookup for puppet

Tags: puppet, hiera

In the course of attempting to debug my puppet manifests numerous times after bundling it with hiera, sometimes I doubt whether the correct hiera lookup is even being performed.

I am mostly using CentOS with Puppet 3.

Is there any tool I can use to find out what hiera data file is currently being utilized for the node I am on, as opposed to trying to guess based on my server config?

Comment: Have you tried verbose output with puppet

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Pass -v when running puppet

Comment: Seems like it also puts green notices in the output, lets me know where the facts are loaded, but no luck with hiera.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the server hosting your puppet master, run `puppet master --debug --compile yournode.example.com | grep hiera`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not sure that would work if I'm running a headless puppet? I'm currently trying out puppet on vagrant.

Comment: I ended up using just the `--debug` flag, which does indeed show the hiera lookup and what backend it is looking at.

Comment: @xiankai Please add some evidence.